# Wordpress media upload error: "An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later"

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I get this error

> An error occurred in the upload

Please try again later" pretty often uploading media from front-end, but not every time and that makes this thing more difficult.

If i log in first time from new browser then i get this error, but if i try more from other profiles i can do uploads, and after a while it appears again.

I these times when i get the error, in developer tools it shows me the error **code 302.**

Comment: I am intermittently plagued by this error uploading media (jpg) files.  To circumvent it I've resorted to either renaming the .jpg and/or resizing (in order to get a new file size).  This usually gets me around the problem for the short term and I can continue.  As a last resort switching to another client computer will provide relief.  I *suspect* some kind of cacheing problem.  The problem is random.  It is perverse and persistent over the short term when it arises; a few hours later it is gone as if it had never been there.  Frustrating as Hades.  Those are my 3 workarounds.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue.

If you have woocommerce, front end manager and stuff like that you have also more than one sign in option, but cannot use regular WP login. Always need to use "My account" or something like that, which belongs to WC. Dashboard seems to be eaqual, but always a permission glitch. :)